# FREEGLUT debug and release lib in Visual C++ 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012, freeglut

Freeglut 2.8.0 builds 4 libs:

x86

> > Debug
> > Release
>
> x64
>
> > Debug
> > Release

However, in the lib directory at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Lib\win8\um there are only x86 and x64 subdirectories.

Where should I put "freeglut.lib" and "freeglut_static.lib" for Debug and for Release? Should I create a subdirectory called Debug and put the debug versions there? And how can my project distinguished upon build?

Comment: For static libs I put them in a \build directory, which is where all of my targets go.  Or you can simply add the path to the lib to your project, one for debug, one for release.

Comment: and the dlls? What difference does it make if I put debug or release in the system dirs, @Robinson?

Comment: dlls you should put in your \debug or \release directory (i.e. whatever the project target is).

Comment: Thanks, @Robinson. It makes more sense then putting everything in the system folders.
Anyway, for projects that constantly use a library, maybe I'll put them in the system.

Comment: I never put anything in "system".  That's bad practice really.  Personally I create a library location that all of my library projects either build to, or copy files to.  You can use this same location for multiple different projects.  i.e. \build\3rd Party Libraries, or similar.

Comment: That is a great tip. Do you put the sources there also, or only the dlls and libs, @Robinson?